# Firefox Drag and Drop - Ghost Image Missing

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

It appears there is a strange issue in FireFox using HTML5 drag and drop.

In Chrome / Safari, a ghost image is generate of the HTML being dragged, but for some reason in Firefox it dosen't seem to be appearing at all.

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="task sortable" draggable="true">
    <input type="checkbox" draggable="false">

<div class="what" draggable="false">
Yet another
</div>

<div class="who" draggable="false">

</div>
</div>
```

JS Snippet within a jQuery dragstart event handler:

```
  var target = $(e.target),
                index = this.$('.sortable').index(target);
            this.dragModel = this.collection.at(index);
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            _.defer(_.bind(function() {
                target.after(placeHolderHtml);   
                target.hide(); 
            }, this));
```

Any ideas why Firefox would not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind I figured out the problem.

It seems FF requires some form of data to be set in the dataTransfer object.

```
dataTransfer.setData('text', 'junk');
```

Fixes it.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let others know this question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future debuggers:

Apparently, a negative text-indent CSS property can also cause the drag image to disappear in Firefox (but not in Chrome/Safari).

Comment: Putting a `translateZ` (and possibly others) transform on the element also causes this.